# Using AND (OR) to select based on multiple row values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create filter query which uses `AND` and `OR` on many to many relation table.

Table consists only of 2 columns `id_product` and `id_category`

My query I'm using, but its not working:

```
SELECT id_product FROM id_category WHERE ( id_category = 1)  AND (id_category = 2) 
AND ( id_category = 3 OR id_category = 4 OR id_category = 5) GROUP BY id_product
```

I would like to retrieve products that are in categories at the same time.
Only IDs of products which are in category 1 AND 2 AND (3 or 4 or 5)

Comment: we need to see the rest of the query because you will likely have to either do multiple joins to the same table or a subquery

Comment: `id_category` cannot be at the same time `1` and `2`.. So seems natural that a `WHERE ( id_category = 1) AND ( id_category = 2) [..etc]` will always return an empty result

Comment: Its a many to many relation as noted in question :) So id_product is not unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must group by id_product and put these conditions in a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT id_product 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id_product 
HAVING 
  SUM(id_category = 1) > 0
  AND
  SUM(id_category = 2) > 0
  AND
  SUM(id_category IN (3, 4, 5)) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, to use a single condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id_product
FROM yourTable
WHERE id_category BETWEEN 1 AND 5
GROUP BY id_product
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN id_category IN (3, 4, 5)
                        THEN 3 ELSE id_category END) = 3;
```

### Demo

The logic here is to first restrict the query to only `id_category` values `(1,2,3,4,5)`.  Then, we assert but first map `id_category` values of `(3,4,5)` to the same single value `3`.  The assertion is that the *distinct* count of mapped `id_category` values is `3`, which would imply that `1`, `2`, and `(3,4,5)` all occur for that product.

Comment: Thank you for answer. great to know, but other one is easier to dynamically build and "seems" faster.

Comment: @Grzegorz Yes, I would probably use the other version in a production code base as well.  I only gave this answer just to show that we can write a more terse query with a little SQL magic ^ ^.